# CRON. Разное время в разные дни недели

Tags: cron

Есть 2 cron выражения, запускающие некоторую задачу.

Один запускает задачу в полночь каждый будний день:

```
0 0 * * 0-4 sometask.sh
```

Второй запускает эту же задачу в полдень по выходным:

```
0 12 * * 5-6 sometask.sh
```

Есть ли способ объединить два данных крон выражения в одно, запускающее задачу в будни дни в одно время, а в выходные в другое?

Comment: Написать две строчки подряд. Зачем усложнять?

Comment: Может и есть какие-нибудь хаки разной степени грязности, но такое выражение будет в разы менее понятно, чем две простые строчки.

Comment: Система, которую использую позволяет ввести только одну строчку.

Comment: Тогда в любой день запускайте дважды, а уже в скрипте игнорируйте неподходящее время.

Comment: Да. Как вариант.